# Convert a map image to black and white

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, cartography, maps

I would like to convert an image from google maps

[image]

into a black and white edition, without gray scale, something that will look like that

[image]

How can this be achieved with `Adobe Photoshop CS5`?

Comment: Have you tried simply drawing it?

Comment: Try to play around with image contrast, gradient map etc.. I do concur with Scott that redrawing the map will probably yield a better-looking result, though.

Comment: @Scott: Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately, I have to include the maps from google, therefore drawing them cannot be applied here. Even if it could, I don't think I could make it look exact;y like google.

Comment: @Bakabaka: Thank's for your comment. I tried to play a bit with B&W filter, contrast but the outcome is always something in gray scale...

Comment: @Thanos: after you've made a greyscale, try using Image > Adjustments > Threshold for a true B&W effect.

Comment: I don't see any way of accomplishing what you are asking unless you draw it. The values in the Google maps are too close to use any automated processes. Your'e comment is a bit confusing - you *have* to use Google maps, but you don't want them to *look like* Google maps - seems to be a contradiction in requirements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I easily turn a Google Maps screenshot into an outline drawing?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15970/how-can-i-easily-turn-a-google-maps-screenshot-into-an-outline-drawing)

Comment: @user568458: Thank you very much for your link! It is really helpfull.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you could probably get without drawing it is to use the `filter > stylize > find edges` (adjusting the contrast first might work better). Once that is applied, use the threshold adjustment to make it black and white.

Here is a quick example of the result:
[image]

Another way is to use the `filter gallery > stylize > glowing edges`. This gives you a smoother line that you can adjust with sliders. Once you've adjusted it, use a threshold adjustment layer (adjust the slider), then invert it with the invert adjustment layer.

Here is what that looks like:
[image]