# Create multiple images with diffrant zoom level from one document in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, workflow, maps, cartography

I’ve following project… (Inspire by [Fastest way to custom design a race course map?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31227/fastest-way-to-custom-design-a-race-course-map?answertab=votes#tab-top))

- Download vector data from www.openstreetmap.org
- Import in Adobe Illustrator
- Dismantle and separate everything on each layers
- Add, delete, modify and complete editing
- Now, I want to save multiple images at macro level to micro level details

  Macro level – At High level with only major details

  Micro level – At low level with all details (I put all low detail on
  separate layer)

It could be explain well with these pictures…

[image: Courtesy cubewerx . com]

[image: Courtesy opengeo . org]

So, for last step, any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Chiku, Welcome to GD.SE! Can you be a little more specific with your question. Right now I am not sure if you're asking how to delete parts of the map, if you're asking which parts of the map to show based on the zoom level you want to show, some type of workflow issue or is your question about saving?

Comment: @AndrewH Thank you for prompt reply,
I’ve edit my question with pictures, hopefully it will be more specify now
I don’t want to delete any part of document but form document I want to create top level Image (Whole city with main road and important landmark) and then low level (Street level with minor detail)

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve but what exactly is the issue your having? You said you already have the extra details on separate layers so it should just be a case of hiding those layers.

Comment: Hi! @Cai I completed work on document and the extra details on separate layers so I could hide at time of generating top level image. Now at last step I want to create different images from street (low) level, so how could Scale or zoom in and generating low level images of document?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a document (or change the one you are working in) to have multiple artboards set up in a tight grid:

[image]

Here you have 16 tiles. Then you add another artboard and make it cover the other ones:

[image]

In "File/Export" you can choose which artboards to save as images. If you save artboard 1-16 you will get the micro level images. Saving artboard 17 will give you the overview image. Make sure to choose appropriate settings in each case.

You can use the same method for even smaller images (but it might be easier to create a new document and let Illustrator distribute the artboards).